# How to show refresh rate of monitor in MS-DOS Version 6.22

Tags: display, ms-dos, refresh-rate, framerate

I was forwarded from Stackoverflow to ask this question here. I am running a psych experiment on an old MS-DOS computer. When I ran the experiment on a different computer that is split via a switch with a computer running Matlab on Windows which uses a different frame rate it seemed to skip some frames. I would like to know the refresh rate from the command line in MS-DOS Version 6.22. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer but do you have a monitor that tells you what refresh rate its signal is? Some display it in the HUD.

Comment: I tried, but it seems it doesn’t do that.

Comment: If you are a programmer and have trouble finding info about your hardware, you could perhaps write a quick tool to do vsyncs and measure the resulting frame rate.

Comment: I suggest you start by trying to identify the video card type (CGA, EGA, VGA, Hercules, etc) and/or the monitor type. Even brands and model names would help. Video cards of that era didn't have "drivers" like we'd think of them, but the files `CONFIG.SYS` and `AUTOEXEC.BAT` in the root directory of the boot drive might have some commands to set video modes or run vendor-specific utilities to set the video card. If you could add some of that information to your question, someone might be able to help.

Comment: Also, you may have to look at the program which you're running to perform the experiment. If it's doing anything "sophisticated" with the display, it may be directly controlling the video card or using an application-specific video driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike windows today, there was nothing built in to MS-DOS 6.22 to look-up there refresh rate unless the software/drivers installed with the hardware device added that functionality.

There *might be* a label on the video card installed stating the spec, or you may need to search (google) for hardware documentation for the video card.

Comment: I suspected/feared.

Answer (score 0):

Google for "VBEhz". Works flawlessly with old videocards. GeForce2MX worked, but GeForceFX5700 and Radeon9600XT didn't.

Comment: These cards didn't even exist when MSDOS 6.22 was released